# Re-instantiate storyboard navigation bar buttons

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have two bar button items set up in storyboard and connected to these outlets:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var sideMenuButton: UIBarButtonItem!

 @IBOutlet weak var selectButton: UIBarButtonItem!
```

When select button is pressed, I replace those buttons with two others, like so:

```
deleteButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Delete", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(deleteButtonPressed(_:)))      
cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelButtonPressed(_:)))

navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = deleteButton
```

Now, I want to change everything back when cancel button is pressed. I am trying to do it by passing the outlets to barButtonItems:

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = sideMenuButton
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = selectButton
```

but this doesn't work and nothing shows up. How can I fix this without having to set up all buttons in code? Is there any way to reset the Navigation Bar or re-instantiate the buttons from storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two outlets are `weak`. So when you are not using them any more, they become `nil`. Remove the `weak` from the outlet declarations and your code should work as expected.